# REST API endpoint for search by file

Tags: rest

I'm working on REST API for search by audio sample.
As far as I know the proper way for search enpoint is like:

```
GET /api/v1/audios?author=test1
```

But since I need search by file I need to use POST (GET doesn't allow file upload). But POST isn't ok for search requests.
Could you advise what is the best solution here: changing of endpoint to suit for POST request or something else?

P.S. sorry for my english)))

Comment: The question is not clear. What is the purpose of the service? Are you trying to upload a file and search the database in the same service?

Comment: > Are you trying to upload a file and search the database in the same service?

Yes. I'm searching matches by audio sample (like Shazam does)

Comment: @VeZooViy how about having another post url for search through which you can have url audio sample in the request body?

Comment: @BalakrishnaAvulapati thanks. I had such idea
But is proper way to solve this in REST?

Comment: @VeZooViy that is how I observed it being implemented in a large scale project. Let me know if you find any other way doing it, I would love to learn. Thanks

Comment: @BalakrishnaAvulapati could you please provide links to some api docs of those projects you mentioned?